# How do I configure my WP7 App with Twitter?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

I'm wondering how do I redirect the app so that it will redirect to the system's integrated twitter (The "post message" button from the "Me" tile) and also how do I integrate a Twitter code to show twitter feeds from ONLY one to three person I specified? (All using VB)

Answer (score 0):

To bring up the Twitter share option you use

```
Dim shareStatusTask As ShareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask()
shareStatusTask.Status = "status"
shareStatusTask.Show()
```

There's no built in way to show tweets in your app so you'll need to write custom code to get that done via the Twitter API.

Comment: How to: Use the Share Status Task for Windows Phone : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#Y0